# How to remove automatic SafeArea from ListView?

Tags: flutter

I just added a ListView as a child of `Scaffold > Stack` and it appears to have SafeArea at the top. Column does not have this problem. Is there any way for me to remove it?

```
Container(
  color: Colors.grey[100],
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Image(
        image: snapshot.data.hero,
        height: 300.0,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

*ListView*
[image]

*Column*
[image]

Comment: Just for reference https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21236

Answer (score 131, accepted):

From the `ListView` documentation:

> By default, ListView will automatically pad the list's scrollable
>   extremities to avoid partial obstructions indicated by MediaQuery's
>   padding. To avoid this behavior, override with a zero padding
>   property.

So the fix is:

```
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  ...
);
```

Comment: Does this hide status bar as well ?

Comment: @B.shruti this does not hide the status bar, it remains on top

Comment: I spent over an hour analyzing my **entire widget tree**, your answer saved me with hot-heload in 1.103 seconds. thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Found this solution as well

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
  context: context,
  removeTop: true,
  child: ListView(...),
)
```

Comment: Thanks to this solution I've been able to reset the top padding added by a widget of an external package. This widget uses a SafeArea on its code so it automatically adds some padding even if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 13):

This is the obviously correct answer:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.zero
```

But I just wanted to add some *additional info* regarding this issue that helped me myself.

If you don't provide padding, it automatically uses parts of MediaQuery.of(context).padding

For example, in a **vertical** list view, the default padding will be this:

```
final EdgeInsets mediaQueryVerticalPadding =
        mediaQuery.padding.copyWith(left: 0.0, right: 0.0);
```

This means if you want to keep the default behavior in one part and change the other values, you should use something like this.

For example, only keeping the Top padding from the MediaQuery and editing the rest:

```
ListView(
    padding: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.copyWith(
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 50,
    ),
    ...
),
```