# Flutter app bar layout: action buttons in the same row with tab bar?

Tags: flutter, material-design, tabbar, appbar

Let's say I would like to create an app bar with two action buttons at the start and in the end while having a tab bar right in the middle, all in the same row. Here is the code I worked on to get the tab bar working:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
            ),
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            flexibleSpace: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                TabBar(
                  indicatorColor: Colors.pink[100],
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'Dogs'),
                    Tab(text: 'Cats'),
                  ],
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                ), //tabbar
              ], //chilren on Tabbar
            ), //new Column
          ), //appbar
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Center(child: Text('DOGS')),
              Center(child: Text('CATS')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

appbar current
[image: appbar current]

app bar expected, with two action buttons (and the indicator position needs a bit more work:
[image: appbar expected, with two action buttons (and the indicator position needs a bit more work]

But how could I add the two action buttons without having the tab bar overlaying them? Using grid maybe?

Comment: Can you add an IMG to this? Current IMG and what is expected?

Comment: yep! IMG added :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to put tabbar into title:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            actions: [
              Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ],
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            title: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
              child:TabBar(
              indicatorColor: Colors.pink[100],
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'Dogs'),
                Tab(text: 'Cats'),
              ],
              labelColor: Colors.black,
            ),),
          ), //appbar
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Center(child: Text('DOGS')),
              Center(child: Text('CATS')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this on Dartpad and I think this method works. Thank you! One more thing though, is it possible to adjust the width of the tab bar inside the title? Or just modify the width of the title directly? Hope that you could clarify on that

Comment: i've updated the answer, just wrap with padding, please mark as an answer if helpful~

Comment: Thank you Jim for your help! And I just noticed the tab indicator position is not quite right. It should be placed at the bottom. Maybe wrap with margin would help.

Comment: yep, a little tune is for perfection, glad it helped!

Comment: Dear Jim, I just went back and try to remove the bottom space under the indicator, but haven't got any luck with that... I saw a very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525806/how-to-remove-bottom-from-default-tab-bar, but the answer to that post did not solve my issue. Could you please take another look? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Hi, I posted another question about this issue, and I got a suggestion of using ```indicatorPadding```, it works fine now :)