# Why my texts are not being displayed in my column?

Tags: flutter, text

I'm a begginer in Flutter and Dart, I have made a simple basic code but it doens't work, someone can help me ?
The app doesn't display the texts of the column.
Here is the code :

```
return CupertinoPageScaffold(
  navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
    middle: Text('Page 1 of tab $index'),
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: const <Widget>[
      Text("ligne 1"),
      Text("ligne 2"),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `text` is already there but it's `hiding` behind the `navigationBar`. Just wrap your `Column` into `SafeArea` and your text will appear properly.

```
SafeArea(
              child: Column(
            children: const <Widget>[
              Text("ligne 1"),
              Text("ligne 2"),
            ],
          ))
```

[image]

Comment: I used with "child : SafeArea("

Comment: You can use as per your need , I just gave you a direction to solve the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope its help to you.

Refer `CupertinoPageScaffold` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageScaffold-class.html)

```
return CupertinoPageScaffold(
       navigationBar: const CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text('Page 1 of tab  index'),
      ),
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("ligne 1"),
          Text("ligne 2"),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Result screen-> [image]

Comment: Thanks it helps, your solution works as well! But do you have an idea why ListView works ?

Comment: By default, ListView will automatically pad the list's scrollable extremities to avoid partial obstructions indicated by MediaQuery's padding. For more info refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52105557/how-to-remove-automatic-safearea-from-listview#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20ListView%20will%20automatically,with%20a%20zero%20padding%20property.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.